# Cómo realizar operaciones matemáticas de valores de una misma columna basados en dos criterios distintos SQL

Tags: sql

Requiero realizar el siguiente cálculo de una tabla sobre valores de una misma columna
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado debe ser

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el Month 1 suma los valores basado en la columna Level1 "Gross Margin" el total es 400 (1500-1100) dividido por la suma de valores de la columna Level0 "Income" (1500) por lo tanto el resultado de la columna ratio para el Month 1 es 400/1500=0,27

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste? Seguro que ya has realizado alguna consulta `SELECT ...`. ¿La compartes?

Comment: Por otra parte, etiquetaste con [tag:sql]. ¿No te referirás a [tag:mysql] específicamente?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Parece ser un cálculo bastante directo, simplemente debes usar una expresión `CASE`:

```
SELECT Month,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Level1 = 'Gross Margin' THEN Amount END)/
       SUM(CASE WHEN Level0 = 'Income' THEN Amount END) as Ratio
FROM TuTabla
GROUP BY Month;
```

Dependiendo del motor de base de datos que estás usando (con lo cual deberías etiquetar tu pregunta) y del tipo de datos, es posible que necesites usar una función de conversión en esa división para obtener resultado con decimales

Comment: funciona ? cree la tabla para ayudar con la respuesta y no me funka ésto

Comment: @FederHico "no me funka" no es muy útil...qué pasa?, lanza error?, resultados incorrectos?, cuál motor de base de datos usaste?

Comment: hice esa tabla en Sqlserver, y me da ratio 0 para todos los meses con los mismos datos del OP

Comment: Lamak muchas gracias, utilizo Filemaker como motor de base de datos y no fue posible etiquetarlo, estoy probando tu solución que seguramente hay alguna diferencia menor en la sintaxis de la expresión.

Comment: @FederHico Es por eso que puse el comentario: `Dependiendo del motor de base de datos que estás usando y del tipo de datos, es posible que necesites usar una función de conversión en esa división para obtener resultado con decimales`. Actualmente estás obteniendo una "división entera", en ese caso puedes usar una conversión a decimal o multiplicar la primera suma por `1.0` para convertirlo a `FLOAT`

Comment: Tienes Razón, declarando la columna amount como float, SUM devuelve floats, funciona Perfecto !

Comment: Muchas gracias ya pude hacer la query y combinarla con fórmulas propias de filemaker, esto debido a que el cáculo de la división no lo estaba haciendo en el lenguaje SQL. el resultado combinando ambos es:
Let (
$result =
 
ExecuteSQL ( "
SELECT Month
    '<',
SUM (CASE WHEN LEVEL1 = 'Gross Margin' THEN Amount END)
,'===',
sum (CASE WHEN LEVEL0 = 'Income' THEN Amount END)
,'>'
FROM MyTable
GROUP By Month
" ; "" ; "";"")
;
Evaluate ( Substitute ( Quote ( $result ) ; [ "<," ; "\"&Round(" ] ; [ ",===," ; "/" ] ; [ ",>" ; "*100;2)&\"" ] )  )
)